# Angular2: Contenteditable div doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, angular, contenteditable

When server stored html text is bound to contenteditable div. The html is not processed and rendered, instead it is rendered as it is.

For example,below html text from server is rendered as text instead of in html.

```
<br>---------- Forwarded message ----------<br>From: Someone &lt;<a href="mailto:sh@gmail.com" target="_blank">sh@gmail.com</a>&gt;
```

Here is the current code:

**HTML Code:**

```
 <div class="description-input" 
             placeholder="Enter Description"
             ion-content
             contenteditable="true"
             [(contenteditableModel)]="description">
        </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnChanges} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: '[contenteditableModel]',
    host: {
        '(blur)': 'onEdit()',
        '(keyup)': 'onEdit()'
    }
})

export class ContentEditableDirective implements OnChanges {
    @Input('contenteditableModel') model: any;
    @Output('contenteditableModelChange') update = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(
        private elementRef: ElementRef
    ) {
        //console.log('ContentEditableDirective.constructor');
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes) {
        //console.log('ContentEditableDirective.ngOnChanges');
        //console.log(changes);
        if (changes.model.isFirstChange())
            this.refreshView();
    }

    onEdit() {
        //console.log('ContentEditableDirective.onEdit');
        var value = this.elementRef.nativeElement.innerText
        this.update.emit(value)
    }

    private refreshView() {
        //console.log('ContentEditableDirective.refreshView');
        this.elementRef.nativeElement.textContent = this.model
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular 2 html binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-2-html-binding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get html then use `innerHTML` instead of `textContent`in `refreshView`

```
this.elementRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.model
```

Similarly in `onEdit`:

```
var value = this.elementRef.nativeElement.innerHtml
```

See also

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: While this works great, you are accessing the DOM directly which is not good :/

Comment: @Abdel If you're not going to use server-side rendering and utilizing Angulars WebWorkers then i don't see this problem https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#declare-directives-and-components

Comment: This works great, but `onEdit` again converts the html to text.

Comment: Replace `innerText` with `innetHTML` within `onEdit` method

Answer (score 0):

Please avoid direct manipulation of the DOM as it goes against the angular 2 mindset.

Did you try utilizing the `innerHTML` directive? [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34424375/4047409)